# Wait for multiple animations in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate two elements.

For the GUI, if either is empty then animate a color in that text box.

Problem is that the function doesn't wait for both of them to animate.

What is the best approach?

I tried `$.when`, `$.promise`. Can't seem to get it working?

**Addition:**

I would like for the two animations to occur if need be.
Once all or no animation are totally done then run the following:

```
if (ChargeID.val() != '' && Quantity.val() != '') {
        test = true;
    }

    else {
        alert('I think you forgot something');
        test = false;
    }


return test;
```

Thanks!

```
function TestValid(button) {

    var ChargeID = $(button).parent().parent().find('input[type=hidden]').eq(1);
    var Quantity = $(button).parent().parent().find('input[name=Quantity]').eq(0);
    var test = true;



    if (ChargeID.val() == '') {

        ChargeID.animate({ "background-color": "#D2F0C9" }, "fast", function () { ChargeID.animate({ "background-color": "#ffffff" }, "fast") })

    }

    if (Quantity.val() == '') {

        Quantity.animate({ "background-color": "#D2F0C9" }, "fast", function () { Quantity.animate({ "background-color": "#ffffff" }, "fast") })

    }


        if (ChargeID.val() != '' && Quantity.val() != '') {
            test = true;
        }

        else {
            alert('I think you forgot something');
            test = false;
        }


    return test;


}
```

Comment: "I tried $.when, $.promise. Can't seem to get it working?" where??

Comment: A few attempts ago, when i failed to save.

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want to happen?  It's just a matter of getting your callbacks to handle the return, but it needs to be in the order you expect.

Comment: @Archer i would like for the two animations to occur if need be. then when if all/any complete return true  or the error message and false;

Comment: What exactly do you want to do when they are both done?

Comment: *"Once all or no animation are totally done return true or 'I think you forgot something' and false."* **that is not possible. The return must happen immediately, and the callbacks are asynchronously happening later.**

Comment: I see them, but that doesn't change my last comment. it's not possible.

Comment: `$(button).parent().parent().find('input').promise().done(handler)`